# 'Failed to add edge detection' -Python Script

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python

I'm trying to count pulses using the GPIO pins and when I run this script I get the error (it's written in leafpad then I open it in IDLE)

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/Pi/Desktop/revcount.py", line 10, in  g.add_event_detect(2, g.RISING, callback = increase rev) RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

Here's the code

```
import RPi.GPIO as g
from time import sleep
g.setmode(g.BCM)
g.setup(2, g.IN)
global revcount
revcount = 0
def increaserev(channel):
    global revcount
    revcount += 1
g.add_event_detect(2, g.RISING, callback=increaserev)
while True:
    sleep(60)
    print "RPM is {0}".format(revcount)
    revcount = 0
```

Comment: Does it work if you run with sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between GPIO numbers and pins is as follows.

```
GPIO       pin  pin    GPIO
3V3         1    2      5V
0/2 (SDA)   3    4      5V
1/3 (SCL)   5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
21/27      13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
           .......
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```

If the GPIO column has a V it indicates the pin is connected to the power rail and not a GPIO.

Where 2 figures are shown separated by a / the first figure is the GPIO number used on the first revision Pi B boards.

Here is a simple RPM counter.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import pigpio # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

REV_GPIO=2    # GPIO getting pulses.
SAMPLE_TIME=3 # Recalculate every SAMPLE_TIME seconds.

pi = pigpio.pi()           # Connect to Pi.
cb = pi.callback(REV_GPIO) # Default tally callback.

old_count = cb.tally() # Pulse count.

try:
   while True:
      time.sleep(SAMPLE_TIME)
      new_count = cb.tally() # Pulse count.
      print("{} RPM".format(60.0*(new_count-old_count)/SAMPLE_TIME))
      old_count = new_count

except KeyboardInterrupt:
   cb.cancel() # Cancel callback.
   pi.stop()   # Disconnect from Pi.
```

Comment: When I run it in Python 2.7.9 it says import error: No module named PIGPIO (I downloaded it and it's there) then when I run it in Python 3.4.2 it says Name error:name 'pigpio' is not defined (referring to line 9) I tried pigpio.py but still get the same error

Comment: To use that pigpio script you would need to download and install the pigpio library (as detailed in http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html) and then start the pigpio daemon (using sudo pigpiod).

Comment: When I try to compile, link and run foorbar.c it gives an error saying No such file or directory

Comment: You only need to do the download and install part.  I.e. "wget abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpio.zip;unzip pigpio.zip;cd PIGPIO;make;sudo make install".  The foobar.c example is a standard way of showing how you would compile your own C code.

Comment: By the way your original script should have worked if you invoked the script with sudo python *script.py* or sudo idle as you were doing.

Comment: Thanks the script is working now but when u touch the two wire together nothing happens, it still keeps outputting RPM is 0. At the moment I've got one wire coming from GPIO 2 and another coming from Ground and then touched the two together. Is this how it's supposed to be connected. (sorry it's my first Pi and Python project)

Comment: What you say should work but only because GPIO 2 (pin 3) has a pull-up to 3V3.  Each time you connect that GPIO to ground and release should register one pulse.  Are you sure you are using the correct GPIO?  As a simpler test just enter pigs s 2 1000.  That will send 50 pulses a second to GPIO 2.  Use pigs s 2 0 to stop the pulses.

Comment: I'm using R-Pi 1st gen Model B and GPIO 2 is pin 13. I did notice that when I connected pin 3 to ground it did output a value but it wasn't the number of times the circuit was closed in a second (I changed the sleep value) it outputted numbers in double digits

Comment: I don't know where you are getting your GPIO numbers from but they are wrong.  See http://pinout.xyz/.  I have added the table I use to my answer.

Comment: It seems to be 'sorta' working. I connected it to Pin 3 and then the other to ground but the figures I'm getting don't really make sense, they're way to high and they range from 1 to 1000+ even though the circuit is being connected 1X.sec so it should be about 60rpm. Also if I closed and opened the circuit faster it didn't seem to affect the output. I just touched the wire from pin 3 to a random piece of metal (pen) once and I got a reading of 1880, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Don't just touch the two wires together.  It'll be like switch bounce you'll get lots of make/breaks in a few milliseconds.  Use PWM to test the software, it doesn't bounce up and down randomly.

Comment: Thanks so much! i tried a couple different switches and now the output values are correct.

Comment: If you are using mechanical switches you might need to filter out the switch bounce.  You can do that with pigpio by setting a glitch filter on the GPIO.  The filter will ignore edges less than a specified length.  See [set_glitch_filter](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_glitch_filter).  E.g. add pi.set_glitch_filter(REV_GPIO, 1000) in the code after the pi = pigpio.pi() line.   That will filter out all edges shorter than a millisecond (1000 microseconds).